# Win32: Get message notification of other application's close/exit

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

My application needs to monitor all other running applications on the system. Is there some way I could get notified on exit of every application exe?

The methods I could find:

1) Use PSAPI functions to get the list of running exes at frequent intervals. At each poll compare with the previous list to find which application/process has exited.
Disadvantage: Requires constant polling, will take CPU time.

2) Set a global hook for WM_CLOSE message: Using this I would be able to get a notification when any application gets closed through the close button on the title bar

Disadvantage:
(-)Not all the applications are generating a WM_CLOSE message(Ex: Total Video Player Exe)
(-)If the application was closed through the "Exit" menu or button (e.g. File->Exit) , I can't trap that message

Is there any other better way that I missed? Please advise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Get a list of PIDs using PSAPI.
2. Then get a handle on each process using [OpenProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320.aspx).
3. Use [WaitForMultipleObjects()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025(VS.85).aspx) to be signalled when one of the processes exits.

Comment: I am getting ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (0x5) both for WaitForSingleObjects and WaitForMultipleObjects. Any idea why this is happening and what am I doing wrong ??

Comment: I can only make guesses: Maybe asking too many access rights? SYNCHRONIZE should be enough. Maybe your user context is not allowed to monitor this process (e.g. simple user can't access system processes. I believe even admin users need admin elevation to access those processes).

Comment: The issue was actually the permissions, so you are right Serge - appTranslator. I used the PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS flag.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [RegisterShellHookWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644989.aspx)() API and filter for HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED and HSHELL_WINDOWDESTROYED messages.

Of course, that will only get you notified about applications that have a window.

Comment: I would avoid registering global hooks except as an extreme last resort.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this problem and found a solution so wanted to share with you all. It all correct the way we should obtain handle to the process. Instead of WaitForSingleOBject though, I would recommend to use RegisterWaitForSingle object function. With this function you are giving a callback function and whenever the process exits, your callback function will be called. This is better than calling WaitForSingleObject in a thread. Calling WaitForSingleObject in your code by itself will cause your code to wait until the process exits. Here is an example of how to call it:

```
RegisterWaitForSingleObject(&waitHandle, processHandle, ProcessTerminatedCallback, param, INFINITE, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE);
```

Where: 
[out]waitHandle - new handle created for you. Please note that you cannot use this handle to call CloseHandle, but you can wait on it, if you want to.

[in] processHandle - handle to the process that you are supposed to obtain yourself

[in] ProcessTerminatedCallback - the callback function that will be called when the process exits

[in] param - LPVOID parameter that will be passed to the callback

[in] INFINITE - either wait infinitely or for a specified time, look up MSDN for more info

[in] WM_EXECUTEONLYONCE - will call the callback function only once. look up MSDN for more info

Comment: Will this explicitly only fire the callback when the process of the input handle ends? Or are there other events that will trigger this, since "WaitForSingleObject" seems vague?

Comment: @oblivioncth, even when it crashes it will be called. It obviously won't be called if the process just hangs there. For that you'll probably need to introduce some heartbeat mechanism, but for that you would have to have access the process's code.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know; however my original confusion was how you determined this function signals the target application closed in the first place. The documentation basically only mentions that the call-back fires when "The specified object is in the signaled state.", which sounds like it could be any number of signals given thr vagueness. Just wanted to be sure this only this only signaled when the process ended (regardless of cause).

Comment: @oblivioncth, I can assure that it works and works pretty well. I've used it in a Windows Service to monitor certain applications that were using its APIs. The applications would store huge amount of data in the service and this was a module that I implemented which was cleaning up the memory that was used by application in case if they had crashed or forgotten to clean up the memory they were using before exiting. The memory was being allocated in the Windows Service space.

Comment: I am confident you are correct in this functions effects, but I wanted to find a statement describing these effects in the official documentation just in case there were any notes or warnings in regards to its usage. I finally did here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/synchronization-objects  -> under Process: "Its state is set to nonsignaled while the process is running, and set to signaled when the process terminates." No other details were given so it does seem to be that straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

*> Is there any other better way that I missed?*

Yes, plenty. See on [Win32 group](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/topics?lnk=srg) (system notifications, without any hook)