# How to detect closing of parent process?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi

I am working on a .NET console app which needs to clean up resources on exit. The problem I'm running into is that I don't get any notification if the cmd parent is closed via the console window [X], via Task Manager/Process Explorer or programmatically with WM_CLOSE. I can live with not being able to handle *Kill Process* from Task Mgr. or ProcExp. WM_CLOSE of the parent console is the most likely way that this application will be closed before it's finished processing.

Here are the events I've tried to register for so far:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CurrentDomainProcessExit;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainUnhandledException;
Console.CancelKeyPress += ConsoleCancelKeyPress;
Application.ApplicationExit += ApplicationApplicationExit;

Process parentProcess = ProcessInfo.GetParentProcess(
    Process.GetCurrentProcess());
parentProcess.Disposed += ParentDisposed;
parentProcess.Exited += ParentExited;

Process grandParentProcess = ProcessInfo.GetParentProcess(parentProcess);
grandParentProcess.Disposed += GrandParentDisposed;
grandParentProcess.Exited += GrandParentExited;
```

These events fire properly when I send a CTRL+C from the console or the application finishes uninterrupted. But none of them fire when the parent app (cmd console) is closed. (The parent/grandparent processes aren't CLR so I'm not sure I would ever receive those Disposed/Exited events. Those are just shots in the dark.) I've looked at some pInvoke stuff but I would rather not go down that road if .NET is an option.

Is there a way to detect and handle a shutdown in these situations? I am open to any .NET, pInvoke/Win32/C/C++ solution. (Basically any way it can be done on the Windows platform.)

Thanks.

P.S. I'm still working with .NET 2.0 so I can't use anything introduced in .NET 3.0+

Comment: What kind of resources do you need to clean up, and what kind of cleanup needs to be done?

Comment: You said the parent is a console app, but then you mentioned WM_CLOSE. Is the parent a console app (in which case it doesn't have a window) or is it a windowed app (in which case you can send it a WM_CLOSE)?

Comment: @John: The process executes other jobs which I need to stop if it is halted prematurely. Otherwise the child jobs are orphaned and run to completion without the spawning process.

Comment: @Gabe: The console window itself can accept a WM_CLOSE and shut down. My process, which started in from that console is brought down too.

Comment: @Paul: and I presume it's a bad thing if the child processes finish what the parent started when the parent is no longer there to watch them? My suggestion would be - make the parent not ever stop - make it a Windows Service, which has a formal concept of starting and stopping.

Comment: @Paul: note, by the way, that this isn't so much a "clean up" task, as a "take some action" task, where in this case "some action" is kill some other processes. Actual "clean up" will naturally happen when the process exits.

Comment: This may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872364/win32-get-message-notification-of-other-applications-close-exit

Comment: @John: That's right. The wrinkle here is that I do need to be able to stop the jobs of my child processes. Handling Ctrl+C works very nicely but that's only available during dev. (This is part of a complex system where several services spawn stdin/out redirected processes which in turn manage other jobs and processes. Users need the ability to cleanly stop an executing process. There are ways, IPC mechanisms for example, but I'm trying to not have to touch the rest of the system. I'm trying to work within the bounds as they exist.)

Comment: @Paul: sounds like UNIX. How would they have done this on UNIX?

Comment: @Jim: That's an interesting link, I'll definitely follow up on it. Any .NET wrappers for that approach that you're aware of?

Comment: @John: You're in the ballpark. This is a multiplatform system with some *nix and Win hooks where necessary. On the *nix side I think they just pass the ETX/0x03 to the parent process/console. On the windows side it's translated to a WM_CLOSE to the console. Not sure why the difference. Seems like WM_CHAR with a 0x03 l/wparam should work in Windows.

Comment: @Paul: yeah, I've seen bad designs like this: using "multiplatform" as an excuse to develop code that assumes a Unix-like environment. My solution was to create a Windows Service to launch the processes, and to kill them when the service received a Stop or Restart command.

Comment: @Paul: None that I'm aware of. It might be a simple matter, though, of creating a thread that does a `WaitForMultipleObjects` on the process handles.

Comment: When you say "manage other jobs", do you mean Windows Job objects as in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161.aspx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is likely to use P/Invoke. The Windows API function `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()` may do what you expect.

Sample code below stolen from [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrnat/archive/2004/09/23/11594.aspx.) (similar code available at MSDN, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s50zac30%28vs.71%29.aspx)).

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    public static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine Handler, bool Add);

    // A delegate type to be used as the handler routine 
    // for SetConsoleCtrlHandler.
    public delegate bool HandlerRoutine(CtrlTypes CtrlType);

    // An enumerated type for the control messages
    // sent to the handler routine.
    public enum CtrlTypes 
    {
        CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
        CTRL_BREAK_EVENT,
        CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, 
        CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
        CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT
    }

    private static bool ConsoleCtrlCheck(CtrlTypes ctrlType) 
    {
        // Put your own handler here
        return true;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetConsoleCtrlHandler(new HandlerRoutine(ConsoleCtrlCheck), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, unfortunately when I looked through the code of the parent application this method was already in use and the events being trapped and not getting to my app. I'll have to go with plan C and implement an IPC mechanism to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The `Exited` event should fire whenever you set `EnableRaisingEvents = true` on the `Process`, regardless of whether the process is .Net, native, or anything else. If you're actually seeing the `Process` exit without the `Exited` event firing, can you post a small reproduction scenario?

Also, the `Disposed` event is useless for your scenario. It only fires when you call `Dispose()` on the `Process` object instance in your process, and has nothing whatsoever to do with anything that happens within the OS process that the object refers to.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem may be that the `ProcessInfo` class in your example is part of the `System.Web` namespace. It (to quote MSDN) "returns information about ASP.Net worker processes that are running under the ASP.Net Process Model." This would seem unlikely to return anything terribly useful to your command-line app.

You need to use WMI via the System.Management namespace. The following sample should do the trick and get you the System.Diagnostics.Process object for the current process's immediate parent. This example uses the `Process.WaitForExit()` method, but wiring up an event handler should work as well.

You should note, however, especially since your talking about a console app, that the immediate parent process is **not** necessarily the process that actually spawned the current process. If process A spawns process console app B directly with `ProcessStartInfo` specifying `UseShellExecute=false`, than A will be the immediate parent of B. However, if process A spawns process B (a console app) with `ProcessStartInfo` specifying `UseShellExecute=true`, then process A will **not** be the immediate parent of process B: there will be an intermediate process (`cmd.exe`) between A and B. And if you're involving *.cmd batch files or PowerShell code...it might be more complicated.

So you might need to run further up of the process tree to find the parent of interest.

Also, since you didn't spawn the parent process, you won't have access to the condition (exit) code of the parent process after it completes. Trying to access the parent process's ExitCode property throws an invalid operation exception.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;

namespace WaitOnParentProcessSample
{
    class Program
    {

        static int Main( string[] argv )
        {
            using ( Process parentProcess = GetParentProcess() )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Waiting for parent process (pid:{0}) to exit..." , parentProcess.Id );
                parentProcess.WaitForExit();
                Console.WriteLine( "Parent Process Has exited. Condition code cannot be determined" );
            }

            return 0;
        }

        private static Process GetParentProcess()
        {
            Process parentProcess  = null;

            using ( Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess() )
            {
                string      filter = string.Format( "ProcessId={0}" , currentProcess.Id );
                SelectQuery query  = new SelectQuery( "Win32_Process" , filter );

                using ( ManagementObjectSearcher   searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher( query ) )
                using ( ManagementObjectCollection results  = searcher.Get() )
                {

                    if ( results.Count>0 )
                    {
                        if ( results.Count>1 )
                            throw new InvalidOperationException();
                        IEnumerator      resultEnumerator = results.GetEnumerator();
                        bool             fMoved           = resultEnumerator.MoveNext();

                        using ( ManagementObject wmiProcess = (ManagementObject)resultEnumerator.Current )
                        {
                            PropertyData parentProcessId = wmiProcess.Properties["ParentProcessId"];
                            uint         pid = (uint)parentProcessId.Value;

                            parentProcess=Process.GetProcessById( (int)pid );

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            return parentProcess;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting thought but these processes are either services or console apps that call another. IIS isn't involved at all.

Comment: What is the actual `ProcessInfo` class you are referencing in `Process parentProcess = ProcessInfo.GetParentProcess( Process.GetCurrentProcess());`? Unless it's some custom code of your own, The only class of that name in the .Net framework is `System.Web.ProcessInfo` and that is specific to Asp.Net worker processes. But either way, querying WMI as in my example code will get you the parent process.

Comment: That's right. It's an in-house utility class. The naming collision never came up as an issue since we don't make use of the System.Web namespace. Still, I think i'll rename it to ProcessUtil or some such to avoid any confusion in the future.